# Finding Top 15 or Top 10% Highest Values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I will have a list of players (for fantasy baseball) that includes what team they are on and their salary - 3 columns in total. The number of players will range but could be in the 100-238 range.  238 is the max though.

I need to find the top 15 or 10% most expensive players, whichever is higher once we're done drafting. Therefore I will either have 15 players (**if my list is <= 150**) or will be the 10% once it gets to 155 and higher (since we're rounding).

Since based on my max I know I'll have anywhere from 15-24 players to pick from I had the following formula in a grid and just dragged down 24 rows. Column I is just numbered 1-24.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$501,"*")  < 150, I3 <= ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$501,"*") * 0.1,2)),INDEX($B$2:$B$211,MATCH(1,INDEX(($D$2:$D$211=LARGE($D$2:$D$211,ROWS(J$1:J1)))*(COUNTIF(J$1:J1,$B$2:$B$211)=0),),0)),"-")
```

However, something is wrong as I keep getting duplicate names when I test this out with test data.

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Comment: **In which columns are the names, teams, and salaries?**

Comment: **Can a salary appear more than once in the list or is each salary unique?**

Comment: Hi Gary, Names appear in Column B, Team in C, Salaries in D.  A salary can appear more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is duplicated salaries.......this can be accomodated......say the data is like:

[image: pic]

Clearly Christopher, Mark, and George all share the same salary...to untangle this in **E2** enter:

```
=RANK(D2,$D$2:$D$23,0)+COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,D2)-1
```

and copy down...........this assigns a unique ID to each record.....In **G2** enter:

```
=MATCH(ROW()-1,$E$2:$E$23,0)
```

and copy down...in **H2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,G2,0)
```

and copy down...in **I2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($C$1,G2,0)
```

and copy down...finally in **J2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($D$1,G2,0)
```

and copy down...........we now have:

[image: next]

This is a "sort-by-formula"..........Pick as many names off column **H** as you choose!

Comment: Thanks Gary.  Going to play around with this now but it definitely works!